# Is it possible to consume positional arguments in pairs with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to consume positional arguments in pairs with **argparse**?

Example:

```
myscript.py [options] NAME URL [NAME URL] [...]
```

I know this can be easily done with optional arguments (using `action='append', nargs=2`), but I still want to do it with positional arguments. (I don't want to change an existing interface.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that argparse doesn't support this usecase directly.
What I did is that I parsed the optional arguments as usually and then added a special `args.name_url_pairs` positional argument and checked the correct number of items (more than two, an even count) manually.